# Can't open MySQL Utilities

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Trying to open MySQL Utilities in the MySQL Workbench and get the following error:

"The command line MySQL Utilities could not be located. To use them, you must download and install the utilities package for your system from www.mysql.com. Click on the Download button to proceed."

However, when I go to the address and download/install, this does not fix the issue.

How do I fix or get around this issue?

I'm running Windows 8.1 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in error the system is not able to recognize it (`MySQL Utilities could not be located`) and in default assumes thats `Python` has been installed and the whole library are developed with [Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-utilities.html) :

> The library is written entirely in Python, meaning that it is not necessary to have any other tools or libraries installed to make it work. It is currently designed to work with Python v2.6 or later and there is no support (yet) for Python v3.1.

so if you don't have `Python` on your system just install and its should fix the problem.